# Seleniumwire not logging all requests in chrome headless mode

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless, seleniumwire

I'm trying to capture all network logs using [seleniumwire](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/). When chromedriver is in normal mode, it is able to capture all requests. But when it is in headless mode, it is not capturing  all requests.

I tried adding `sleep(10)`, `assert driver.last_request.response.status_code == 200`
 but neither helped.

Since `seleniumwire` is not that popular, I'm adding a sample guide below in the hope of getting people with knowledge of selenium to try a hand to help me fix the problem.

**Working with seleniumwire**

Installing seleniumwire

```
pip install seleniumwire
```

Sample script:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver  # Import from seleniumwire

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Go to the YouTube homepage.
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com')

# Access requests via the `requests` attribute
for request in driver.requests:
    if request.response:
        print(
            request.path,
            request.response.status_code,
            request.response.headers['Content-Type']
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

try to capture all requests

```
options = {
'ignore_http_methods': []  # Capture all requests, including OPTIONS requests
}
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\chromedriver.exe",seleniumwire_options=options)
```

In default it ignores OPTIONS method